# refreshing browser multiple times causes server to hang

Tags: apache2, settings, virtualhost

I run virtual server on apache2 and debian with 700mb memmory. I noticed that after hitting ctrl+f5 multiple times (10 - 15) causes server to hang. There is no info in logs. By just plain watching memmory behavior using htop command, I can see that memmory hit the top and swap started to rise. It takes about 3-4 minutes for the site to be responsive again. 
My apache2.conf settings :

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers          3
MinSpareServers       6
MaxSpareServers      6
MaxClients           15
ServerLimit      15
MaxRequestsPerChild 500 
</IfModule>
```

What settings should I tweak to prevent such hangs? 
Doe's this mean, that if 10 or more visitors come to my site, the site would become unresponsive? My goal is to be able to serve pages for at least 20 users a time. 
Thank you.

Comment: are you connected to database? and closing connections, datareaders after using them?

Comment: @DavorMlinaric I can not access database during hang. If I let browser open, It would load page at the end of hang.

Comment: i know, check in code if you are closing your connections to database after reading data... somehow i suspect on that.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric I am not sure how to do that, I use drupal and after googleing, there is no mention of such problem with drupal installations. I tried to set max clients and max serverlimit to 20  but it did not help.